# Titletoc + multitoc : conflit on \@starttoc

Tags: tables, macros, table-of-contents, titletoc, multitoc

I got an troublesome issue when using both titletoc and multitoc. In short, code looks like this :

MWE :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{apl}

\titlecontents{lstlisting}[2em]
              {\addvspace{0.25pc}}
              {\textbf{Code \thecontentslabel} }
              {}
              {\titlerule*[0.5em]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}
              []

\makeatletter

  \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
  \newcommand\appendixlistingname{\lstlistlistingname}
  \newcommand{\listofappendixlistings}{%
  % Applying the same trick as listings does with \lstlistoflistings: Modifying \@starttoc such that it can load only .apl files
    \begingroup
      \let\@starttoc@orig\@starttoc%
      \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\appendixlistingname}
      \renewcommand{\@starttoc}[1]{%
        \@starttoc@orig{apl}%
      }%    
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixlistingname}
      \tableofcontents% Calling \tableofcontents with the `.apl` file instead of `.toc`
    \endgroup
  }

  \newcommand{\appendixFix}{%
  \setcounter{lstlisting}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{theHlstlisting}{%
    }{%
      \renewcommand{\theHlstlisting}{appendix}
    }%
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\latex@tf@lol\string\tf@lol% Store the original `\tf@lol` file handle
    \string\let\string\tf@lol\string\tf@apl% 
  }%
}{}{}

\makeatother

% Backup
\let\backupCommand\lstlistoflistings
\let\backupCommandZ\listofappendixlistings

%\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
%\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{YOLO}

\backupCommand

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}

\appendixFix

\begin{appendices}
    \backupCommandZ
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test2]
        Some code
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Without multitoc, it produces an listing for each part (main and appendixes) :

[image]

[image]

But when I uncommented the 3 multitoc lines, the list of listings for both part are broken.

Any solution ?

Thanks

PS: I check in the the two files that stores references (.lol for main ,apl for appendixes) have expected contents after the compilation.

**main.lol**

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {5.1}Exemple des fonctionnalités de Lodash}{30}{lstlisting.5.1}%
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {5.2}Axios : Exemple d'utilisation d'une POST request}{32}{lstlisting.5.2}%
```

**main.apl**

```
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {B.1}{\ignorespaces \ignorespaces {Exemple d'une ressource information avec notre norme}\relax }}{97}{lstlisting.appendix}%
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {D.1}Point d'entrée d'une application, sur base de Yargs}{111}{lstlisting.appendix}%
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {D.2}Exemple d'une implémentation d'une commande "Yargs"}{111}{lstlisting.appendix}%
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax 
\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {D.3}Implémentation de la recherche par \glspl {tag}}{112}{lstlisting.appendix}%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ijon Tichy (from LaTeX.org), I know the reason behind this bug :

> Years ago I've send a bug report to the package author, because
>   multitoc disables @starttoc for all files but toc, lot and lof. He
>   answered, that he does not support the package any longer and he
>   recommends not to use it any longer.

To anyone interessted, here is my solution :

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\beautifultableofcontents{%
    \begin{multicols}{\multicolumntoc}[\section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \end{multicols}%
    }

\makeatother
```

Which can be invoked like :

```
\beautifultableofcontents
```